# why the .LogIn class,has margin-top that i can not ,change it to smaller size?

Tags: html, css

In This Code,I want to set the margin-top of .Login class ,smaller,although I set The margin-top ,to zero,but it is not set near to  the top of page.What Can I do?why by setting the margin-top of this division ,this div does not set ,near the top of page?is other thing ok?the other elements works properly.

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    direction: rtl;
}

@font-face {
    src: url('../fonts/IRANSansWeb.eot'), url('../fonts/IRANSansWeb.woff'), url('../fonts/IRANSansWeb.woff2'), url('../fonts/IRANSansWeb.ttf');
    font-family: "IranSans";
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 700px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #007bff;
}

nav {
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
}

nav ul {
    width: 60%;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}

.Logo {
    width: 160px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.Logo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.LogIn {
    width: 140px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 130px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-family: "IranSans";
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #00d363;
}

.LogInA {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
}

.LogInA:hover {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: #00d363;
    border: 1px solid #00d363;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="Logo"><img src="Content/img/logo.png" alt="جاب بورد"></div>
            <ul>

            </ul>

            <div class="LogIn">
                <a class="LogInA" href="#">ارسال شغل</a>
            </div>


        </nav>




    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display: flex;` to your nav

Answer (score 0):

You should use:
 `display:flex; justify-content: center;` to your Nav and also you should remove height and use: `flex-direction:column;` in mobile version.